# Find a sine equation with those minimum & maximum point

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Question: Determine  a sine/cosine equation of the form

$$ y = A \sin  ( b  x - c)   $$

with minimum point at $(\frac{\pi}{4}, -2)$ and its nearest maximum point to the right at $(\frac{3\pi}{4}, 4)$

What I could find was the amplitude and the period but not phase shift $c$ as in:

$$y=3 \sin (2x) + 1$$

How can I find the phase shift?

Comment: I think the most intuitive way is to try to figure out what point of the wave hits the $y$-axis.

Comment: We know the high and low points, so where are the middle points? Figure that out then draw a graph.

Comment: Also, giving the min and the nearest max point, they have given you the period

Answer (score 1):

The low point of your curve is at $x=\frac {\pi}4$ and the high point is at $x=\frac{3\pi}4$, so the midpoint is at the average of those two values, $x=\frac{\pi}2$.

The midpoint of the sine curve happens when the parameter is zero. So we need
to shift the graph of the sine curve by $\frac{\pi}2$, and that is the phase shift.

So the function is

> $$y=3\sin\left(2\left[x-\frac{\pi}2\right]\right)+1=3\sin(2x-\pi)+1$$

We can use the fact that $\sin(u-\pi)=\sin u$ to rewrite this as

> $$y=-3\sin 2x+1$$

Either should suffice.

Comment: Nicely explained. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can take $y=-3\sin 2(x-c)+1$,

so letting $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ gives
$\;-3\sin 2(\frac{\pi}{4}-c)+1=-2$,

so $-3\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-2c)=-3\implies\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-2c)=1$.

Taking $\frac{\pi}{2}-2c=\frac{\pi}{2}$ gives $c=0$, so you can use $y=-3\sin 2x+1$.

Answer (score 0):

As the constant term does not involve sine/cos with frequency term $2x$ there is no further phase shift !

EDIT1:

In Electrical engg. standard  phase shift angle  with respect to inflection point of wave  $y(t)$ waveform on $t$-axis is given by $ \phi:$

$ y(t) = A \sin (\omega t - \phi) + C $

where A is amplitude, $\omega $ frequency $C$ is a constant bias. $ \phi $ always occurs *within* the argument.